# AWS SES - Listing email identities with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I'm sending emails to verified identities in AWS SES with ASW Lambda without problems.
Now I'm just trying to list verified identities and getting no response.

Here is my code:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def list_identities():
    ses = boto3.client('ses')
    response = ses.list_identities(
      IdentityType = 'EmailAddress',
      MaxItems=10
    )

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    print("Listing EMAILS:")
    list_identities()
```

In function log I see printed *Listing email:* and nothing else.
Lambda function is invoked in same region as AWS SES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return anything from your function.

Try this:

```py
import boto3


def list_identities():
    ses = boto3.client('ses')
    response = ses.list_identities(
        IdentityType='EmailAddress',
        MaxItems=10
    )
    return response


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    print("Listing EMAILS:")
    print(list_identities())
```

Comment: Silly me, can't believe I omitted that. And to see anything on output you need to use    'print(list_identities())'

Comment: Happens to the best of us. :)

Comment: And to see anything on output you need to use  print(list_identities()). Just address this somehow so I can accept answer..